# PHP keep input type=date value after form submit

Tags: php, html, onchange

i want to keep my input type=date value after onchange form submit

**Current HTML code**

```
             <input type="date" id="Date" name="Date" placeholder="Date" value=”<?php echo $_POST['Date'];?>” onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

So after onchange, I want the value of the date remain same. I tried many ways but it didn't work. Thanks for helping

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What does  `$_POST['Date']` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this, I am seeing issue with quote as well in your HTML, so copy below code to see.

```
<input type="date" id="Date" name="Date" placeholder="Date" value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['Date'])?date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_REQUEST['Date'])):'';?>" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work on my side. It will still go back to dd/mm/yyyy after onchange.

Comment: what is form method?

Comment: I have updated code to $_REQUEST for all method type.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

You're not using standard double quotes `"`, but a curly variant, which are not part of the HTML standard:

```
value=”<?php echo $_POST['Date'];?>”
```

Replacing those curly quotes by straight ones will fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i not sure which one you talking about. i tried your code and its not working on my side

Comment: "My" code is just an extract from yours, this is where you've written curly quotes.

Comment: Please be warned that this makes your application vulnerable for XSS attacks. All user-supplied input should be escaped before writing them to the markup

Comment: @NicoHaase Not sure why you commented here, as the XSS vulnerability is from the question?